# Reference for Woman's testimony worth half of a man's?

Tags: edim-witnesses, gender

I have heard that a woman's testimony was considered half of a man's. Please share the references. https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/witness

Comment: I recommend you ask the person from whom you heard it.

Comment: @msh210 That comment isn’t really in the spirit of this site